# Add field for dynamically generated url in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a Django model that has a property called `url` that when accessed, returns a S3 signed url of a document on s3. Sign URLS have expirations, so I am not saving to the model, it needs to be generated when the model is accessed.

I want to add this dynamic attribute to the admin section when the document is accessed (but this is not a field saved to the model, it is a property on the model)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Declare your property on the model (or, if you like, the admin)
2. Add the property to the `readonly_fields` attribute of the admin
3. Add the property to the `fields` or `fieldsets` attribute of the admin

EG:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # fields here

    def s3_url(self):
        return ... # some calculated URL

class MyAdmin(admin.Admin):
    readonly_fields = ('s3_url',)
    fields = (..., 's3_url')
```

It shouldn't make a difference whether or not `s3_url` is literally a property, declared using the `@property` decorator, or just a callable. The only catch is that some of the callable attributes like `short_description` that let you customize the behavior don't work perfectly with `@property`.

Comment: Also worth noting that readonly_fields must come before fields